# Ember afterRender component / non-async AJAX

Tags: ajax, ember.js

Imagine a component that renders an HTML table. The data from the table comes from remote JSON.

Another part of the component relies on the HTML table being fully rendered (with the JSON data).

On the component's `init` event, I retrieve the JSON and set the data that the component will use to render the table.

I can't use an `afterRender` hook to further process the table, because when the `afterRender` is fired, the table exists but without the JSON data.

I noticed that an `afterRender` hook outside the component works (the table is fully rendered), but then I'd break the encapsulation by running code that belongs inside the component.

I could maybe get the JSON synchronously, or perhaps a promise within a promise? How would I do the latter? What I mean is on the component's `init` hook, how do I create a promise which returns only when the promise inside it is returned?

Or how can I approach this the Ember way?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely chain the hell out of your promises.

```
var items = [];

this.set('items', items);

$.getJSON('/colors').then(function(results){
  results.forEach(function(item){
    item.color +=" is pretty";
  });
  return results;
}).then(function(prettyResults){
  prettyResults.forEach(function(item){
    items.pushObject(item);
  });
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/724/edit

Super deep convoluted promises

```
new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
  resolve($.getJSON('/colors'));
}).then(function(results){   // this isn't hit til the json is returned
  results.forEach(function(item){
    item.color +=" is pretty";
  });
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
    Ember.run.later(function(){
      resolve(results);
    }, 4000);
  });

}).then(function(prettyResults){ // this isn't hit til the 4 second resolve is done
  prettyResults.forEach(function(item){
    items.pushObject(item);
  });
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/725/edit

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for teaching me something I'm going to need :) However, I think I just found a better approach for this particular case. If I "observe" the property that the HTML table depends on, inside the observer the table is fully rendered, so I can do what I need! Sweet.

Comment: Ivan listening for state of model to become loaded is the way to do it (DS.Model#isLoaded), please consider answering your own question. Also take a look at this article http://blog.trackets.com/2013/01/27/ember-data-in-depth.html.